# Longitudinal Study with variable sampling periods

Tags: time-series, modeling, longitudinal-data-analysis

I came across a dataset of a longitudinal study that has the following characteristics:

1. Participants enter at any time in the study
2. They can exit the study at any point for various reasons but cannot re-enter
3. Samples are taken at semi-random intervals (e.g >2 months from each sampling period to the next but can be up 3 months or 1 year).
4. Each subject has at least 3 samples (but can have e.g. 7).
5. Each subject is monitored for a different amount of time.
6. At each sampling point a few thousand parameters are recorded.
7. The disease is in general progressing across time.

I am familiar with different time-series / repeated measures models but they require a more well defined structure. Many of the characteristics of the study are similar to a survival analysis, especially the flexibility of observations, monitored time, etc.
Furthermore, the great number of parameters measured is also a factor to take into account.

Do you know of a model that can tackle elegantly this setup?

Correlations of clinical variables across time as well as a linear/mixed model are definitely within the list but I was wondering if there is something that seems to address this setup better